# Power Query create PIVOT but each Pivot column should have their "sub-column"

Tags: excel, powerquery

Title explained: I have a txt file, I read it into excel, create a Query to edit it. My txt file is [shop.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHt0j.png), contains the following (*1):

| Material nr | Shop | Trouser | Size | Trouser Color | Available amount | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 621077453 | Target | XXL | Black | 20 | Male |  |
| 621077453 | Tesco | XXL | Black | 12 | Male |  |
| 623989211 | Target | S | Black | 22 | Male |  |
| 630136378 | Lidl | L | Black | 21 | Female |  |
| 678048334 | Target | M | Red | 33 | Female |  |
| 678048334 | Tesco | M | Red | 15 | Female |  |
| 680603975 | Target | S | White | 30 | Female |  |
| 680603975 | Tesco | S | White | 20 | Female |  |
| 680603975 | Lidl | S | White | 33 | Female |  |
| 688820171 | Target | XS | Blue | 32 | Male |  |
| 688820171 | Lidl | XS | Blue | 15 | Male |  |

Then I create the query from range("A:F"), remove the empty values, and create a pivoted version of itself:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Material nr.", Int64.Type}, {"Shop", type text}, {"Trouser Size", type text}, {"Trouser Color", type text}, {"Available amount", Int64.Type}, {"Gender", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Material nr."] <> null)),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Shop]), "Shop", "Material nr.", List.Sum),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Target", "Tesco", "Lidl", "Trouser Size", "Trouser Color", "Available amount", "Gender"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

It brings me to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXLL3.png)
I need as many columns as many different Shops available. But the catch is: I need every material to be listed **only once**, and every extra data (Size, Color...) should appear with the pivot's name. Manually naming it isn't a problem at all. If I do it the only way I know, the additional data for the materials gets dropped off (so I end up left with the |Material nr| and |Shop| to work with). 
 
 The table I am looking for is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA3e0.png).
[image]

Is this even achievable somehow? It looks so messed up for me. I am almost sure it is possible to create the targeted table in VBS, but I am trying to get better with Power Query.
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in Powerquery.  You unpivot, combine the two columns, then pivot back.  Gender would show up as a column when there is data in there.

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Shop", "Material nr"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Shop", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.None),"Header"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Merged Columns", List.Distinct(#"Merged Columns"[Header]), "Header", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Note if you feel like it, also read in the text file directly without needing to load the data into an excel table first

```
let Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.txt"), null, null, 1252)}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("___", QuoteStyle.Csv) ),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Split Column by Delimiter", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"Shop", "Material nr"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Shop", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.None),"Header"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Merged Columns", List.Distinct(#"Merged Columns"[Header]), "Header", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how did you solve it so fast, I couldn't even understand the first text, showing errors for me, but the second one did work well, thanks!